# How exactly would I take the open file and the names that are in the files and put them into my string vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char response = 'y';
    while (response == 'y')
        do
        {
        const int numberofnames = 200;
        vector <string> boynamevector(numberofnames);
        vector <string> girlnamevector(numberofnames);
        ifstream readboy;
        ifstream readgirl;
        string boy;
        string girl; 
        int choice;
        readboy.open("BoyNames.txt");
        readgirl.open("GirlNames.txt");
        bool check = true;
        int boychoice = 1;
        int girlchoice = 2;
        int bothchoice = 3;
        for (int counter = 0; counter < numberofnames; counter++)
        {
            readboy >> boynamevector[counter];
            readgirl >> girlnamevector[counter];
        }
        cout << "\t\Popular Boy or Girl or Both Choices\n\n"
            << "1. Popular Boy Name\n"
            << "2. Popular Girl Name\n"
            << "3. Popular name for both Boy and Girl\n"
            << "Enter choice: ";
        cin >> choice;
        if (choice == boychoice)
            cout << "Enter a boy's name: ";
        cin >> boy;
        check = false;
        int counter;
        for (counter = 0; counter < numberofnames; counter++);
        {
            if (boy == boynamevector[counter])
                check = true; 
        }
        if (check == true)
            cout << "The name is popular\n";
        else
            cout << "The name is not popular\n";
            cout << "Would you like to run the program again? \n"
            << "Enter y for yes or n for no: ";
        cin >> response;
        } while (response == 'Y' || response == 'y');
    return 0;
}
```

I think the problem is in the first for loop that appears. I'm not sure that the names are being transferred from the open file to the string array/vector and I'm not entirely sure how to make that work. If anyone could help or give some suggestions that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also when I run this code I get a vector subscript out of range error. What is that all about?

Comment: You're not checking whether the files were opened successfully.

Comment: That does make sense. Such a noob mistake.

Comment: I just think in the first loop the file isn't filling the strings. Like it just overlooks the first loop and goes onto the choices.

Comment: That's not the problem. The loop is okay. (Provided there are at least 200 names separated by whitespace in both files.) Try to print the contents of the vectors as you read them and see what they contain. Also check jhnnslschnr's answer, he's got a good point.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo:

```
for (counter = 0; counter < numberofnames; counter++);
```

That semicolon makes the next lines be a normal block, so `boynamevector[counter]` is out of range.

Comment: I see exactly what you are saying and that made a huge difference.

Answer (score 0):

First you need properly read all the boys and girls names BEFORE you enter the loop so you don't re-read the names over and over again:

```
string response = "y";
ifstream readboy;
ifstream readgirl;

//Open the files
readboy.open("BoyNames.txt");
readgirl.open("GirlNames.txt");

if(!readboy.is_open())
    return 0;
if(!readgirl.is_open())
    return 0;

vector <string> boynamevector;
vector <string> girlnamevector;
string szName;
while(getline(readboy, szName))
    boynamevector.push_back(szName);
while(getline(readgirl, szName))
    girlnamevector.push_back(szName);

readboy.close();
readgirl.close();
```

Then iterate over and over comparing the strings

```
do
{
    string boy;
    string girl; 
    int choice;
    bool bExists = true;
    int boychoice = 1;
    int girlchoice = 2;
    int bothchoice = 3;

    cout << "\tPopular Boy or Girl or Both Choices\n\n"
        << "1. Popular Boy Name\n"
        << "2. Popular Girl Name\n"
        << "3. Popular name for both Boy and Girl\n"
        << "4. Exit\n"
        << "Enter choice: ";
    cin >> choice;
    if(choice == 4)
        break;

    if (choice == boychoice)
        cout << "Enter a boy's name: ";
    if (choice == girlchoice)
        cout << "Enter a girls's name: ";

    cin >> boy;
    bExists = false;

    //Find the name
    if(choice == 3 || choice == 1)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < boy.size(); i++)
        {
            if (boy == boynamevector[i])
                bExists = true; 
        }
    }
    else if(choice == 3 || choice == 1)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < girlnamevector.size(); i++)
        {
            if (boy == girlnamevector[i])
                bExists = true; 
        }
    }

    if (bExists == true)
        cout << "The name is popular\n";
    else
        cout << "The name is not popular\n";
    cout << "Would you like to run the program again? \n"
        << "Enter y for yes or n for no: ";

    cin >> response;
} while (response == "Y" || response == "y");


return 0;
```

Comment: Besides a few things that I had to fix, this code worked better than mine did. Thanks I appreciate the help.

Comment: Make sure to read through the comments and why things were done the way they were done. Notice that reading the file ONCE works better than re-reading it over and over, also notice the logical checks for boys/girls names